# Intellij Scala Worksheet error (osx)

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea

I am just starting out with Scala and running a simple worksheet on Intellij 2016.1 /osx.

I've installed scala/sbt via homebrew. I've also installed the scala plugin for Intellij. When I create a simple worksheet and put "Hello.." in it, and run the worksheet I get this error. I've google'd enough and cannot find any reason for this..thoughts?

```
Internal error: xsbt.CompilerInterface
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.send(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcVI$sp(RemoteServerRunner.scala:33)
scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.run(RemoteServerRunner.scala:30)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.server.RemoteServerConnector.compileAndRun(RemoteServerConnector.scala:85)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.processor.WorksheetCompiler$$anon$1.run(WorksheetCompiler.scala:78)
com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:196)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```